# Drupal 8 strange caching issue

Tags: caching, twig, browser-cache, drupal-8

I have weird caching issue on Drupal site.

First D8 page caching is turned off.

Then I have some content on page that changes for every page loading - to make it simple I'm printing current time from twig template:

```
{{ "now"|date("H:i:s") }}
```

It works like this:

- After clearing Drupal's cache and opening the page I can see current time, as expected
- When I reload the page I still see previous time (I'm logged in as master admin). No matter how many times I reload the page I see time of the first page loading after clearing the cache
- When I open the same page from another browser for the first time I see current time and after that for any reload I see time of the first page opening in that browser
- When I inspect page loading from browser it says that page is loaded from server  - not cached by browser
- Clearing cookies doesn't help. For the first time I clear the cookie I get logged out and I see current time once, but for every other cookie clearing I see the same time.

Any idea what is happening here and how to disable that caching?

Comment: MilanG .. Did you find the solution for the above issue

Comment: Yes, as I commented bellow. It was block cache, as @lamp5 explained. Might be that it was cached by varnish (ESI includes) ?

Comment: MilanG .. Do you know, how to avoid the page level caching, Only for a single twig file.

Comment: Not sure that you can do it for single twig file (please correct me if I'm wrong), but only for blocks. http://purencool.com/how-to-stop-a-specific-block-from-being-cached-in-drupal-8

Comment: yeah block level i know, i do have a requirement to avoid the cache for a single twig file.Do let me know, if you have any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your themename.theme file

```
function themename_preprocess(&$vars, $hook) {
  $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
}
```

and clear cache.

Edit, on drupal.org you can read good guide how to prepare your development environment and disable cache during development. [Guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914)

Comment: It was some block cache, but it's disabled the way you described here. Strange that even in back-end all caches are disable D8 is still caching the content.

Answer (score 0):

You need juste to disable Internal Page Cache Module and clear cache

Comment: Can you describe this procedure further?

Comment: @Oualiiid Could you please explain it clearly. Your solution is to avoid cache for a single page right ??

Comment: Just find the module in back-end modules page and disable it. But I'm afraid that it will turn off caching for absolutely all static content that was cached for anonymous users.